# Как сделать чтобы функция выполнялась только тогда, когда выполнились оба условия?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как сделать чтобы функция выполнялась только тогда, когда выполнились оба условия?
Необходимо, чтобы блок становился серым только при условии, когда нажата кнопка **И** курсор был убран с самого блока. 
Сейчас на **mouseleave** не реагирует

```js
$reservation.on("click mouseleave", function () {
    $(this).text("Подробнее");
    $(this).parent().css("filter", "grayscale(100%)");
});
```

```css
.block{
  width: 200px;
  height: 175px;
  display: inline-block;
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  transition: 1s;
  color: steelblue;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/223/200/150" alt="">
    text
    <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/222/200/150" alt="">
    text
    <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/225/200/150" alt=""/>
    text
    <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При клике, в объекте элемента можно сохранить любой индикатор, что он был кликнут. А потом при mouseleave проверять его.

```js
$('.button').on('click', function(e) {
  this.bubu = true;
});

$('.block').on('mouseleave', function() {
  var ths = $(this);
  if ( ths.find('.button').prop('bubu') ) { // Если не кликали, будет undefined (false)
    ths.find('.button').text("Подробнее");
    ths.css("filter", "grayscale(100%)");
  }
});

$('.block').on('click', function(e) {
  if ( $(e.target).closest('.button').length ) { return; }
  // e.target - элемент. на который кликнули. 
  // Если кликнули на кнопку - то .length будет 1 (true) - функция прервется
  // А если клик любом другом месте - оно будет 0 (в логическом контексте - false)
  var ths = $(this);
  ths.find('.button').prop('bubu', false);
  ths.css("filter", "grayscale(0%)");
});
```

```css
.block{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  transition: 1s;
  color: steelblue;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/223/200/150" alt=""> text
  <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/222/200/150" alt=""> text
  <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/225/200/150" alt="" /> text
  <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Блок становиться серым когда курсор сходит с кнопки, а надо чтобы когда курсор сходил с самого блока

Comment: @Imp3l подправил*

Comment: не подскажете, как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на весь блок, он снова становился нормального цвета?

Comment: @Imp3l добавил. А если захочется при этом сохранить предыдущий текст кнопки и потом возвращать его вместе с цветом - этот текст точно также можно хранить где-нибудь в другом свойстве, аналогично bubu )